# Vertx HttpRequest .basicAuthentication() vs .putHeader("Authorization", "...")

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

Why does the following results in an "Unauthorized" response:

```
 webClient
            .getAbs("http://hello.com")
            .basicAuthentication("user", "pw")
            .rxSend()
            .subscribe();
```

Whereas the following works fine:

```
 webClient
                .getAbs("http://hello.com")
                .putHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("user:pw".getBytes()) )
                .rxSend()
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the implementation for `basicAuthentication`

```
    Buffer buff = Buffer.buffer().appendBuffer(id).appendString("-").appendBuffer(password);
    String credentials =  new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(buff.getBytes()));
    return putHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION.toString(), "Basic " + credentials);
```

It puts `user-pw` not `user:pw`.

Comment: You are totally right! This seems to be a bug since the java doc of the method says otherwise.

Comment: This has been fixed and is available since version 3.7
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/commit/a7def14fba4589c1b112489d837658455f8f4301#diff-6d762e73191a4cf2bb08e92dac3ca550

Answer (score 0):

The method description conflicts with the current implementation, since it says "joined by a colon", so I guess this is a bug. Im currently using version 3.6.3.

```
  /**
   * Configure the request to perform basic access authentication.
   * <p>
   * In basic HTTP authentication, a request contains a header field of the form 'Authorization: Basic &#60;credentials&#62;',
   * where credentials is the base64 encoding of id and password joined by a colon.
   * </p>
   *
   * @param id the id
   * @param password the password
   * @return a reference to this, so the API can be used fluently
   */
  @Fluent
  HttpRequest<T> basicAuthentication(String id, String password);
```